# Requirejs shim: want to register backbone plugins directly into core backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, requirejs, shim

I got two small Backbone plugins which look like this:

```
(function($, _, Backbone) {

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
// blablabla
});

Backbone.ListView = ListView;

})($, _, Backbone);
```

and

```
(function($, _, Backbone) {

var Repository = Backbone.Model.extend({
// blablabla
});

Backbone.Repository = Repository;

})($, _, Backbone);
```

I now have set up require.config:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: "javascripts",

    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: "$"
        },
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "ListView": {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
            exports: "Backbone.ListView"
        },
        "Repository": {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
            exports: "Backbone.Repository"
        }        

    },

    paths: {
        "jquery": "Vendors/jquery",
        "underscore": "Vendors/underscore",
        "backbone": "Vendors/backbone",
        "ListView": "Extensions/ListView",
        "Repository": "Extensions/Repository"
    }

});
```

And now we come to the problem. This is how I currently have to handle module dependencies if I want to use both plugins:

```
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'ListView', 'Repository'], function($, _, Backbone1, Backbone2) {

    // this is backbone + list view
    console.log(Backbone1);
    // this is backbone + repository
    console.log(Backbone2);       

});
```

But I would like to have the plugins already registered into backbone:

```
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {

    // this now is backbone + listView + repository
    console.log(Backbone);

});
```

How do I do this?
What do I have to change?

Best regards, 
bodo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest first of all to create modules for `ListView` and `Repository` to keep them (and hopefully `Backbone` as well) out of the global namespace, like this:

list_view.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
  Backbone.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ... ListView code here ...
  }
  return Backbone.ListView
});
```

repository.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
  Backbone.Repository = Backbone.View.extend({
    ... Repository code here ...
  }
  return Backbone.Repository
});
```

Then you can use require.js' [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) config to map dependencies to an adapter where you include both modules, and then undo the mapping for the `list_view` and `repository` modules themselves to avoid circular dependencies:

```
requirejs.config({
  map: {
    '*': {
      'backbone': 'backbone-adapter'
    },
    'list_view': {
      'backbone': 'backbone'
    },
    'repository': {
      'backbone': 'backbone'
    },
});
```

Then create a file `backbone-adapter.js` to bundle the plugins with Backbone itself:

backbone-adapter.js

```
define(['backbone', 'list_view', 'repository'], function (Backbone) {
  return Backbone;
});
```

Then in your modules, when you include `'backbone'` as a dependency, requirejs will map that to `backbone-adapter`, which will in turn include your plugins so that they are available as `Backbone.ListView` and `Backbone.Repository`.

I haven't actually tested the code above but I use a similar strategy for bundling vendor modules with my own plugins and it's worked fine for me. (The idea is taken from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/requirejs/Z_-_l4jwJ_4/1q5YiYc9VsIJ).)

Comment: thank you for your detailed example! I should have mentioned that my lib is not really a backbone extension it is actually something totally different I just tried to use backbone to make it more "realistic". However I think I can "copy" the idea with mapping an adapter.

Comment: Oh I see. Well the general idea of adapters is pretty useful for bundling dependencies together, so I'm sure you can re-apply it to whatever situation you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do things like that, you're creating a global object containing all your modules, this is not how require.js is intended to be used.

You should explicitly define your dependencies. If you need `ListView` then add it in the require call, if you need `Repository` add it in the require call, ...

---

If you still want to do that, you can define your own Backbone module:

```
# backbone.js

define(['vendor/backbone', 'ListView', 'Repository'],
  function(Backbone, ListView, Repository) {

    Backbone.ListView = ListView
    Backbone.Repository = Repository

    return Backbone
});
```

And then your shim config:

```
paths: {
    ...
    "backbone": "backbone",
    ...
}
```

(Again, you should really not do it!!)